# Encoding issue with HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, .net, http, encoding

Running the below code with Fiddler shows that plus signs are getting converted to a white space char of some sort. What encoding should I use to keep the data from being converted? I would like to keep the plus signs, etc.

**EDIT:** Updated code example

```
string postData = "test1=test+plussign&test2=another++twoplussigns";
private static byte[] EncodePostData(string postData)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    string[] pairs = postData.Split('&');
    foreach (string pair in pairs)
    {
        string key = Uri.EscapeDataString(pair.Split('=')[0]);
        string value = Uri.EscapeDataString(pair.Split('=')[1]);

        sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&",key, value);
    }
    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);

    return HttpUtility.UrlEncodeToBytes(sb.ToString());
}
```

And here is the calling method

```
byte[] data = EncodePostData(postData);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; fr; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092510 Ubuntu/8.04 (hardy) Firefox/3.03";
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
stream.Close();

HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Response.Close();
```

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your variable is called `postData`, I'm going to assume you're making a HTTP POST to a web server.

[Wikipedia's summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) of the rules for HTTP POST is:

> When a web browser sends a POST request from a web form element, the
>   default Internet media type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".
>   This is a format for encoding key-value pairs with possibly duplicate
>   keys. Each key-value pair is separated by an '&' character, and each
>   key is separated from its value by an '=' character. Keys and values
>   are both escaped by replacing spaces with the '+' character and then
>   using URL encoding on all other non-alphanumeric characters.

That is, the default interpretation of `'+'` in a HTTP POST body is an encoded `' '` character. You need to escape your data properly, by calling [Uri.EscapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx) or [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx).

```
Uri.EscapeDataString("test+PlusSigns"); // returns "test%2BPlusSigns"
```

Alternatively, use [HttpUtility.UrlEncodeToBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s1sz54z.aspx) and write the resulting bytes directly to the request stream (without using a `StreamWriter`).

(Note that if you are sending key/value pairs, you need to escape each key and value independently, then join them with `'='` and `'&'` characters.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried it and updated the OP to reflect the new code. Now Fiddler shows that "data" is getting it's = and & encoded so it's one big string now instead of separate params.

Comment: That's because you're only supposed to UrlEncode the _values_ (the key is before the =, the value is after, each key/value pair is seperated by ampersands), not the entire POST string.

Comment: @Jon C: The final call to `HttpUtility.UrlEncodeToBytes(sb.ToString())` is incorrect; this is double-escaping your submission. Your string is already URL-encoded at this point. Since it should now consist solely of ASCII characters, you can use `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString())` to get the bytes to post to the server.

Comment: @Task: Strictly speaking, _keys_ need to be escaped too (although having `=` or `&` as part of the key name would be unlikely in most cases, and not recommended in all).

Comment: @BradleyGrainger Duh, as the name suggests UrlEncodeToBytes :) Thanks for pointing that out. Let me give it a whirl and I'll let you know how it went.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string postData =  Uri.EscapeDataString("test+PlusSigns");
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(postData);
writer.Close();

HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Response.Close();
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't change anything. I've also tried the UTF8Encoding class.

Answer (score -1):

The maximum you could do is set the request content type

```
myReq.ContentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
```

Comment: He is asking about the data he is setting on the request, not about what he is getting back.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I update the question to clarify. What I'm sending in is exactly what I want, but it appears it's getting encoded by the HttpWebResponse, when I view it in Fiddler, it's wrong and not exactly what I sent over.

Comment: @Anand +1 for trying to help :)